# Macros iterating over undefined Symbols

Tags: macros, clojure, metaprogramming

When applying a macro multiple times with a another macro, bare Symbols are not inserted into the current context:

```
(defmacro ty [type]
  `(deftype ~type []))

(defmacro empties [& args]
  (doseq [arg args]
    `(ty ~arg))
  )

(empties Base Person Animal)
;equivalent to:
;(ty Base)
;(ty Person)
;(ty Animal)


(derive ::Person ::Base)
(derive ::Animal ::Base)
(ty Me)
(prn ::Me)
(prn Me)
(empties Empty)
(prn ::Empty)
(prn Empty)
```

The last line gives: "Unable to resolve symbol: Empty in this context", even though when using the direct macro ty, it works. Any way to solve this? If possible without eval it would be much better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FWIW, I prefer to write @Svante's solution as

```
(defmacro empties [& args]
  (cons `do
        (for [arg args]
          `(ty ~arg))))
```

which is also pretty close to the structure of your `doseq` approach.

Comment: @daniel-ribeiro Works for me. `user=> (empties Empty) | user.Empty | user=> (prn Empty) | user.Empty`.

Comment: Thanks @kotarak. I've used it on REPL, and it worked fine. LaClojure for Intellij screws up something and it doesn't work. Weird. I apologize for not trying on the REPL before.

Comment: Note: this answer is correct and simpler than Svante's. However, his answer explains why this one is correct. Would love to be able to choose both.

Answer (score 5):

```
(defmacro empties [& args]
  (doseq [arg args]
    `(ty ~arg)))

(empties Base Person Animal)
;equivalent to:
;(ty Base)
;(ty Person)
;(ty Animal)
```

This is wrong.  Your `empties` call means that the macro expansion function for `empties` gets as arguments the symbols `Base`, `Person`, and `Animal`.  It then evaluates the `ty` macro call for each, but does not return anything, as `doseq` always returns nil.  So, the expanded code from that `empties` call is nil.  You need to return a single form from your macro function.  You should wrap the multiple forms into a `do`, and actually return all the subforms to that:

```
(defmacro empties [& args]
  `(do ~@(map (fn [arg]
               `(ty ~arg))
              args)))
```

Comment: Interesting. Note that your solution doesn't seem to work for me though: I get IllegalArgumentException: Don't know how to create ISeq from: clojure.lang.Symbol on the "do" line

Comment: `(fn [arg])`, not `(fn (arg))`. But he's right in general: `doseq` is usually wrong in a macro, though of course it's fine to expand *into* a `doseq` if that's the goal.